# Application Insights Referesh When using API

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to use application Insights API get some telemetary and use it in my website.
During my testing i navigate to some pages in website and then call api but that doesnt get the latest pages i go to

Is there any setting that should be done on azure to make make api get latest pages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should expect a delay between the data generation and data available for querying. Typically latency is in single minutes range. And it is typically smaller for metrics than for raw events.

[SLA for Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/application-insights/v1_0/) is 2 hours:

> "Data Latency" is the number of minutes that data received from the instrumentation in Customer’s application is delayed from appearing in Application Insights service where the delay is greater than 2 hours.

Comment: But if i explore the demo app that Microsoft offer for testing i can see what i opened when query it after one or two minutes at most


https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&eventType=pageViews

Comment: Yes, as I said the typical latency is in single minutes. One or two. 2 hours is an official SLA that Application Insights guarantees